# I had a problem with the format of the json array when it was transferred to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

server: rails

client: jquery

When I tried to transfer the array of objects to the server, I found the following problem in the background log

request params:

```
"networkslicesubnet": {
  "managed_function_info" => [{
    "AmfFunction" => {
      "pLMNIdList" => "1",
      "aMFRegionId" => "2",
      "aMFSetId" => "3",
      "aMFPointer" => "4",
      "sBIFQDN" => "5"
    }
  }]
}
```

background log display:

```
"networkslicesubnet": {
  "managed_function_info" => {
    "0" => {
      "AmfFunction" => {
        "pLMNIdList" => "1",
        "aMFRegionId" => "2",
        "aMFSetId" => "3",
        "aMFPointer" => "4",
        "sBIFQDN" => "5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Request parameters obtained by the browser development tool:

```
networkslicesubnet[managed_function_info][0][AmfFunction][aMFRegionId]=&networkslicesubnet[managed_function_info][0][AmfFunction][aMFSetId]=&networkslicesubnet[managed_function_info][0][AmfFunction][aMFPointer]=&networkslicesubnet[managed_function_info][0][AmfFunction][sBIFQDN]=
```

I guess it's because ruby will change a[0]=1 to a: {"0"=>1}

Comment: is this a form submission?

Answer (score 0):

i'm just know so so your problem, please detail more.
but try my solution:

catch params like this

```
   def your_params
     params.require(:networkslicesubnet).permit(:managed_function_info => {})
   end
```

and use this in your action function

```
your_params.to_h
```